# What permission is required to create a Service Hook in Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: azure-devops

In Visual Studio Team Services on the tab for "Service Hooks", some of our project team members get an message that says  "You do not have sufficient permissions to view or configure subscriptions."

What permission or group do they need to be assigned in order to create a Service Hook for a given project?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to add user to Project Administrators or Project Collection Administrators group.

Comment: user voice feedback to [allow more granular control](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/20312194-make-service-hook-permissions-more-flexible) then project admin

Comment: @spottedmahn This is now here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365713/make-service-hook-permissions-more-flexible.html

Answer (score 5):

For some reason on TFS 2017 RTM, some projects' Project Administrators could create Service Hooks and some could not.

I had to run the following from tfssecurity.exe:

```
tfssecurity /a+ /collection:[TFS_Collection_URL] ServiceHooks PublisherSecurity/[Project_GUID] EditSubscriptions n:"[User_ID]" ALLOW
tfssecurity /a+ /collection:[TFS_Collection_URL] ServiceHooks PublisherSecurity/[Project_GUID] ViewSubscriptions n:"[User_ID]" ALLOW
```

More information:

- [Rest API on getting Project GUIDS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/projects#get-a-list-of-team-projects)
- [MS TFS Service Hook Q/A](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/marketplace/integrate/service-hooks/troubleshoot#q--a)
- [MSDN forums: What permissions do I need to set up a subscription](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0618ae2a-35c0-4ae1-a43a-3db8cc33531b/what-permissions-do-i-need-to-set-up-a-subscription?forum=tfsadmin)

Comment: NB: For anyone working with Azure DevOps Services (i.e. the cloud version), folllowing some of the examples for tfssecurity elsewhere on the web you may get error `TF21002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server`.  If you'd included `/DefaultCollection` on the end of your TFS_Collection_URL try again without it.  You should now be prompted for credentials & hopefully all will now go smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the following method and it worked:
Firstly turn the project to be public and then you can see the service hook settings become available. Set up the hook and then turn the project back to private and the hook still works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the permissions from the top answer (Project Admins and Project Collection Admins) and it still didn't work for me. After some research, it seems like there is some kind of auth cookie issue.

A temporary fix that worked for me was to use a different browser or an incognito window. It seemed to actually use my new permissions this way.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score -1):

I encountered this in Azure Dev Opps and the issue was due to my Project Visibility settings being set to "Private" rather than "Public".

e.g. https://dev.azure.com///_settings/projectOverview
When I changed Visibility to "Public" from "Private" I gained ability to "+ Create Subscription"

It seems that even if you are in the correct Administrators groups, you may be blocked if your project visibility is private.

Comment: Not true, switching a project visibility from private to public in my organization did not change a thing as far as creating service hooks is concerned. And yes, I relogged, used a different browser and incognito mode. No difference.